# Connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to mongodb Error

Tags: mongodb, express, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I deployed the mongodb on my GCP Compute Engine using the bitnami, but my mongodb it's not starting after a restart of my GCP machine, getting the following error:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.6 
connecting to: mongodb://ip:27017/admin?gssapiServiceName=mongodb 
2019-04-02T10:22:05.815+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect 
to server ip:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: 
Error connecting to ip:27017 
:: caused by :: Connection timed out :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:343:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```